# Uncertain Timer calls on RaspberryPi3 with Python and wxPython

Tags: wxpython, raspberry-pi3, python-3.7

I have simple application with *Python 3.7.2* and *wxPython 4.0.4* which trying to catch event of pressing real button connected to GPIO and after that run some RFID scanner over serial port.
This application has two `wx.Timer` - one for updating UI the second is for pooling button events, then start the scanning periodically.

While this application works perfectly on different PC (like some laptop with i3 CPU), even if the button is connected with `gpiozero` and `pigpiofactory` (remote GPIO), when is started from RaspberryPi the timers are just not running together. I can't see any errors nor warnings in logs. Just whatever timer start first, never allow to start the other one.
I'm starting both with `wx.CallAfter()` so I just don't know if this is not related with just one core of RaspberryPi? What should be my approach to solve this problem?

[EDIT]
Important parts of code:

```py
import rfid_frame
from gpiozero import Button
import wx


class RfidFrame(rfid_frame.MainCounterFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        rfid_frame.MainCounterFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Show(True)


def green_button_held():
    global pressed, frame
    if pressed:
        print('OFF')
        pressed = False
        wx.CallAfter(stop_timer)
    else:
        print('ON')
        pressed = True
        wx.CallAfter(start_timer)


def start_timer():
    timer_scan.Start(2000)


def stop_timer():
    timer_scan.Stop()


def on_timer_scan(event):
    global tags
    frame.m_rfidCount.SetLabel("{:d}".format(tags))


def start_timer_ui():
    timer_ui.Start(1000)


def on_timer_ui(event):
    global frame, bgcolor, fgcolor
    frame.m_rfidCount.SetBackgroundColour((bgcolor))
    frame.m_rfidCount.SetForegroundColour((fgcolor))


def rfid_init():
    global button
    button = Button(4)
    button.when_held = green_button_held


def window_init():
    global app, timer_ui, timer_scan, frame
    app = wx.App(False)
    timer_ui = wx.Timer(app)
    timer_scan = wx.Timer(app)
    timer_ui_id = timer_ui.GetId()
    timer_scan_id = timer_scan.GetId()
    app.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, on_timer_ui, timer_ui, timer_ui_id)
    app.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, on_timer_scan, timer_scan, timer_scan_id)
    wx.CallAfter(start_timer_ui)
    frame = RfidFrame(None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window_init()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[EDIT2]
As [Marcos G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11476836/marcos-g) suggested in comments, I used also timers ID. But still have the same issue.

Comment: are you using different IDs for each timer? it's difficult to explain why your code will behave either on a RPi or any other architecture if you don't show it...

Comment: The code is attached.
Also the `rfid_frame` is really simple, has just `StaticText` and required containers (everything made with wxFormBuilder).
I though about IDs but why this code working on regular PC then? The same versions of Python/wxPython. Modules installed with `pyenv` and `pip freeze` from `virtualenv`.

Comment: If by regular PC you mean Windows I think the fact that your (no offense intended but incorrect) code works is not at all a guarantee it will work on Linux. Sometimes things are very different at the OS level. I'd suggest you try to use IDs. [This](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/) is a very good resource in case you need some pointers

Comment: No. I don't use Windows. PC that I work on Debian Buster with exactly the same version of Python I get on latest raspibian - installed with `pyenv virtualenv` - and same for other modules. Then code is deployed on multiple raspi devices with gitlab-runner. So still, everything is on Linux and only architecture is different. Code itself works on raspberry fine. If I don't use Timers, but from main loop do some one time calls with wx.CallAfter - the UI or the GPIO events and serial communication with scanner works as should be (although only once).

Comment: No idea, but depending on how these timers are implemented the difference in architecture (ARM vs. x86-64) could explain the difference. Other than adding IDs I cannot offer more advice. If you want to know the hows and whys you need to dig into the code, probably all the way to the kernel, lots of fun ahead if you have the time

Comment: This wasn't answer that I expected... but was afraid of ;) But thanks anyway.